# returning pdo rowCount variable

Tags: php, pdo

I have a Usertable on which i want to include pagination depending on the number of entries in this table,but I just can't figure out how i get access to the $counter value. I've already tried for quite some time now, but am at the end of my knowledge here. I hope someone of you can help me out.

View:

```
<?php if(($this->counter) > 5): ?> show pagination;
```

Usermodel:

```
public function index()
{
    return $query = $this->db->sql('SELECT id, user, role, email, status, fname, lname, address FROM users');
}
```

UserController:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->view->users = $this->model->index();
    $this->view->counter= ;
    $this->view->title = 'Users';
    $this->view->render(USERS . 'index');
}
```

Mainmodel:

```
class Model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

}
```

Database file:

```
class Database extends PDO

    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . '; dbname=' . DB_NAME . '; charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        }

        // SELECT
        public function sql($sql, $placeholders = array())
        {

            $query = $this->prepare($sql);
            foreach($placeholders as $key => $value)
                $query->bindValue($key, $value);
            $query->execute();
            $counter = $query->rowCount();
            return $query;
        }
```

Comment: not sure if I'm missing something, but aren't you returning the query instead of the rowCount ?  $counter = $query->rowCount();
            return $query;

Answer (score 0):

Generally the Controller should access the values from the Model. From here, the View should be able to use values retrieved by the Controller. Idea is Model<->Controller<->View. This was high level but hope it is of any help!

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jack, but i do understand the basic structure. I just already removed some of the code of my failed attempts, that's why there is no call to it in the Usersmodel. I'm mostly having issues because i externaly call the Database/PDO functions. and don't quite know how to return the value over several files.

Answer (score 0):

Ask three programmers to define MVC and you’ll probably get four different answers.

I’m going to propose a little twist to the previous answer, in that my practice is to make the controller skinny.  Does the controller need to know  about a counter? No. In fact, I would argue that it should have no knowledge of it.

When your controller hands over the model to the view, that should be the end of it. The view can glean any presentation data it needs from the model.

Your model should be able to tell you how many rows it’s ready to give you, so just ask for it (call a method) in the view.

Don’t misunderstand what I’m saying: the view isn’t the place to do any serious computing; it should only do what is necessary to display your page. It should be almost all html (or whatever medium you’re using).

So after the long explanation, I would say let your view simply ask for it from the model the controller gave it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment tim. with that input i found a way around my problem and fixed the issue for now. It may not be the most elegant way of doing it but it works.